# Multiple series of footnotes with and without period after \thefootnotemark

Tags: footnotes, punctuation, koma-script

I am in the final stages of editing a complex document with different series of footnotes — mainly, a normal series using Arabic numerals and a second set using an asterisk. (Because this is a critical edition of previously published documents, in a few places there are also supplementary footnotes with letter "a" following them: "5a", "27a", and so on.)

At the moment, all footnote marks in the actual footnotes are followed by a period. But the author has requested that the asterisks not be; the Arabic (and Arabic plus "a") footnotes should continue to be followed by a period.

At the moment I am using `scrextend` (KOMA-Script) to specify that a period follows `\thefootnotemark`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[hang,multiple]{footmisc}

% Extra footnote numbers with "a" appended
\DefineFNsymbols*{extraFnNumbers}{{5a} {42a} {27a}}

% Required for footnotes with "a" appended
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup} 

% Special asterisk-marked footnotes
\long\def\asteriskfootnote#1{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[1]{#1}\endgroup} 

% Footnote mark is followed by a period
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1.7em]{1.6em}{2em}{\thefootnotemark.\enskip}
\title{Book Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter Title}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\asteriskfootnote{Note with asterisk 
here.} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\footnote{Note with Arabic numeral here.} 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\setfnsymbol{extraFnNumbers}\symbolfootnote[1]{Note with Arabic numeral plus 
``a'' here.}

\end{document}
```

My question is: can I define `\thefootnotemark` differently for the two different kinds of footnote, so that the asterisks are not followed by a period but all the others are?

Comment: Please provide an example that compiles without error. In your code snippet, `footmisc` with the `multiple` option is incompatible with `scrextend`.

Comment: Yes, sorry — adding `\documentclass` is necessary here. MWE now complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[hang,multiple]{footmisc}

\newif\iffootpunct
\footpuncttrue

% Extra footnote numbers with "a" appended
\DefineFNsymbols*{extraFnNumbers}{{5a} {42a} {27a}}

% Required for footnotes with "a" appended
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup} 

% Special asterisk-marked footnotes
\long\def\asteriskfootnote#1{\begingroup%
\footpunctfalse
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[1]{#1}\endgroup} 

% Footnote mark is followed by a period
% \usepackage{scrextend}% functionality is part of scrbook
\deffootnote[1.7em]{1.6em}{2em}{\thefootnotemark\iffootpunct.\fi\enskip}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill%just for the example

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\asteriskfootnote{Note with asterisk here.} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\footnote{Note with Arabic numeral here.} Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\setfnsymbol{extraFnNumbers}\symbolfootnote[1]{Note with Arabic numeral plus ``a'' here.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's very clever.