# KOMA-Script \thanks command and biblatex-chicago

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, biblatex-chicago

I am setting an article using the KOMA-Script class `scrartcl`. I need a footnote to the title, and I obtained it by using the `\thanks` command. As per the KOMA-Script Guide, this produced an asterisk in the title and an asterisked note at the bottom of the title page preceding the numbered notes in the body of the article, beginning at number one. But I am dealing with references with `biblatex-chicago`, which assigns a Chicago-style format to footnotes that begins: [indent][full-size note number on the baseline][period][space][text of note ...]. That is fine for the numbered notes, and for the spacing of the title note, which should match that of the numbered notes. However, it gives a note marker "*." which is surely wrong, and certainly not Chicago style (Online Chicago Manual para 14.24: "If a symbol rather than a number is used [...], the symbol appears as a superscript in the text but not in the note, where it is not followed by a period but may be followed by a space, as long as this is done consistently.").

How can I get "*" as the note marker, rather than "*." when annotating a title in class scrartcl?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[notes,strict,backend=biber,%
bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{document}
\title{Title\thanks{note}} 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: In German I would say: „Ich verstehe nur Bahnhof.” [You've already been told to always show a MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397687/koma-script-and-captionformat). Please do so and use it to make your question more clear.

Comment: Add `footmarkoff` to your biblatex-chicago options. A similar problem appeared earlier here today (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399808/105447).

Comment: If that's not quite what you want, you may try lockstep's answer to [Multiple series of footnotes with and without period after \thefootnotemark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154391/105447).

Comment: A very low hack, which might be useful, but certainly not recommended, would be `\thanks{\kern-5pt \textcolor{white}{\rule{5pt}{1ex}}note}` (requires `xcolor`).

Comment: Thank you gusbrs--I used the low hack, since this is very much a one-off problem for me, and it worked. The `footmarkoff` solution would, I think, have made all my footnotes revert to the KOMA-script default format rather than the desired Chicago style, and i wasn't sure how to integrate lockstep's solution with `\thanks`.

Comment: The dot after there asterisk from the `\thanks` is the same dot as the dot of a normal `\footnote`. An this is what @BenBrewster wants to get rid off.

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily redefine the footnote making command.

[image: Title sample]

...

[image: Footnote samples]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[notes,strict,backend=biber,%
bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nodotfn}{\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{
      \setlength\parindent{1em}%
      \noindent
      \makebox[2.3em][r]{\@thefnmark\hphantom{.}\,\,}##1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
{\nodotfn
\title{Title\thanks{Note}}
\author{Author}
\maketitle}

Text\footnote{More}.
\end{document}
```

This redefinition is just `biblatex-chicago`'s definition, with the fullstop replaced by `\hphantom{.}` to preserve the spacing.  It is important you enclose the use of the function in a group, otherwise its effects spill over to the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

In KOMA-Script syntax the footnote-definition of `biblatex-chicago` is more or less:

```
\deffootnote[2.3em]{0em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\,\,}
```

You can adapt this for the title page with an invisible `.`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[notes,strict,backend=biber,%
bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}
%\deffootnote[2.3em]{0em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\,\,}

\begin{document}
\title{Title\thanks{note}} 
\begingroup
\deffootnote[2.3em]{0em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\hphantom{.}\,\,}
\maketitle
\endgroup

Test\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also activate the commented line to reactivate all KOMA-Script features for the document footnotes.